# Sorting Array of Custom Class Objects

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am facing problem that is of sorting. The scenario is explained as: i have a class (Suppose of person) and it has suppose 4 attributes (firstName, lastName, Address, salary) i am creating its object and making a collection of all attributes and putting this object in a NSMutableArray and so on. So at every index of array i have one object (i.e collection of 4 attributes). Now i want to sort that array on the basis of salary can anyone help me out regarding this problem, will be thankful.,

Comment: The title is confusing, I thought this was about arrays of classes.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for NSArray.  It has several sorting methods.  Search for the word "sort" and you'll find 'em.  (You'll want either the block based or function based API).

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"salary" ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: sorter];
    [yorArrary sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: @Ishu, Maulik:

I have implemented like that but my program giving me the exception "Thread1: Program received the signal: SIGABRT" and is crashed

NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"salary" ascending:YES] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: sorter];
    [appDelegate.ContactArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
 
any idea about this behaviour??

Comment: Ishu actually i donot exactly know what and where the error is, just when reaches this line

[appDelegate.ContactArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

program crashed and just receiving this log message "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'"

Comment: This does not show complete message pls give complete exception.

Comment: really nothing else is there, the message is same as i have already told u:(
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

Comment: Then you need to debug carefully check you make appDelegate object correctly . and accessing array gives you array object.Also use NSZombie.

Answer (score 0):

Either you implement a compare-method for your object:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Person *)otherObject {
return [self.birthDate compare:otherObject.birthDate];
 }

 NSArray *sortedArray;
 sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

or usually even better: (The default sorting selector of NSSortDescriptor is compare:)

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthDate"
                                          ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```